# SQLite. Как получить данные за месяц?

Tags: android, sqlite

Как получить все записи за месяц так, что бы проверялись все записи от начала до конца месяца? Дело в том, что я не знаю сколько записей будет в месяце, поэтому хочу как то составить запрос, что бы он проверял все записи от первого числа месяца до последнего.

p.s. Для уточнения, хочу сделать график с суммой за месяц, но сколько в месяце записей-неизвестно, поэтому хочу проверять один месяц, потом следующий и так далее от первой до последней записи.

Думаю использовать следующую логику: находить дату самой первой записи, от нее высчитывать начало месяца и делать последовательные запросы в диапазоне [начало мес + 30 дней].

Дата хранится в `COLUMN_DATE + " TEXT, "`

В качестве примера (дата / какие-то данные которые надо получить за месяц):

```
1529913482 | 500

1534319881 | 250

1538035081 | 320
```

Comment: Напишите в вопросе какой формат поля таблицы, который дату хранит. И пример самих данных

Comment: покажите пример данных

Comment: чтобы получить записи за июнь - select * from table  where  datetime(column_date,'unixepoch')>='20180601' and datetime(column_date,'unixepoch')<'20180701'

Comment: или же переводите начало/конец месяца strftime('%s','20180601') в unix и сравнивайте без конвертации